# Best Resource for Intense Solidity Coding (In May 2018)

Tags: solidity

Learning Solidity seems like it's constantly in flux. Some code I had written previously is no longer cool (example: declaring the contract name in the function is no longer bueno!)

As of right now, where would a Pretty Good Code Writer (get it?) go to have a *boot camp, intense, trial by fire, shame you if you suck,* course?

Currently, I've only found the following (my comments on them included).

https://ivanontech.teachable.com/p/blockchain-fundamentals
Ivan is a funny dude and passionate about the technology so this might be a win. But it hasn't started yet. Plus this looks a little elementary. I'm a HARD CORE wannabe -- I know what a hash is, I know what a variable is, I know the difference between "integer" and "Boolean", I can write if- and/OR statements)

https://www.udemy.com/blockchain-developer
This one has been around for awhile.  I know this because I enrolled in it in mid 2017. It's done a decent job of keeping up, but honestly these poor guys are only getting a couple bucks an enrollment... **It costs $9.99 to enroll!! That's outragous!** I wouldn't be inspired to keep it up to date. If I were to recommend one, this would be it, but again it lacks the passionate "**here is our course, do it or you suck!**" attitude.

https://blockgeeks.com/guides/solidity/
This one turns up `#1` on google searches but it just lists off a bunch of examples. I know this sounds ridiculous, but I'd rather spend money, get some dude to give me some web exercises, and then publicly humiliate me when I don't do them.

https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/solidity/
This seems more like a cure for insomnia than something I could actually learn from. However it does come highly recommended by Google and if I weren't typing this while being poisoned by a bartender, then this might actually be useful.

Okay but seriously (as if any of you were not taking this seriously to begin with!). Where can I go to spend like $100, and get an intense course that kicks my brain around? There are all kinds of javascript courses like this as well as other languages.

Business idea for someone? Customer number 1 is waiting to signup!

Comment: All of the below answers are useful so please give them a tick if you can. I went with first option as he gave several and Crypto Zombies looks fun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One resource that I really love is **[crypto zombies](https://cryptozombies.io/en/course/)**, it walks you through building an erc721 game (like crypto kitties) with you having to write portions of code to unlock next levels it even includes some front end courses and it's free

a second course on **[bitdegree](https://www.bitdegree.org/courses/solidity-smart-contract/#)** has the same interactive coding concept but it's more basic solidity stuff

And one of my favorite blogs which is actually created by a very active member on this stackexchange **[@smarx](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/19510/smarx)** it contains very up to date solidity code and some blog posts on the ethereum ecosystem too **[program the blockchain](https://programtheblockchain.com/)**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think [Ethereum and Solidity: The Complete Developer's Guide](https://www.udemy.com/ethereum-and-solidity-the-complete-developers-guide/) on udemy is the best one to learn solidity.I am also biased towards this course because its taught by my favourite tutor Stephen Grider.He is really passionate towards teaching & ensures that you wont carry home any doubts.

As for the syntax of solidity is concerned, it keeps changing from time to time.You should know that its still on version 0.Once it reaches version 1, it will become more stable.A way around this is to first write your code in Remix, and then copy-paste it into your code editor.By doing this Remix will notify you about any errors or syntax changes beforehand.

And last but not the least, passion is the only component required to learn anything.If you have enough of it, you will surely find a way.

And note that cost does not always determine quality.So dont think that you require a costly course or class to learn something.Actually in today's world knowledge is free but what most people dont have is time!

Answer (score 1):

You will get an intense and personal training program and a challenging certification exam from https://academy.b9lab.com/courses/course-v1:B9lab+ETH-25+2018-06/about.

Disclosure: I am one of the mentors.

Hope to see you there.

Comment: Hi Rob - quick question. Is the Consensys Academy course the same as the B9Lab course, just with a different wrapper? If so, does that mean you're one of the mentors there as well?

Comment: It was as you describe in 2017 but I have no first-hand information about their program this year.